# SHA256 hashing with C# and openTK

Tags: c#, .net, hash, sha256, opentk

As you can probably guess im looking to create a bitcoin miner but the cryptography really isnt my thing and i've been unable to find much help through google, so how does hashing with standart openCL actually work?

(Yes, i know its a broad question but any pointers would be highly appreciated)

Comment: This is indeed way too broad for the Q&A format of stack overflow. Have you tried anything and are hitting a specific roadblock?

Comment: Well the main problem is that i am unsure of how parallel processing works and i had hoped someone here could give me some guidance...

Comment: If you don't know a lot about crypto or parallel processing then a GPU accelerated crypto-currency miner might be too big a step. You should probably take some time to learn the theory behind them and make some simpler things before jumping into this project. This question is definitely too broad for this site unfortunately.

Comment: Well if you don't know anything about crypto why do you try to create a bitcoin miner? And for what purpose?

Comment: Ugh, i hate to admit that you are right...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is available in the .NET Framework, have you seen the `SHA256` implementations in `System.Security.Cryptography`?

[MSDN - SHA256](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: No, that solution uses the CPU for hashing and for a bitcoin miner the CPU is much too slow and generally inefficient.

Comment: @OgnianMirev To be fair at this point in BTC's life the GPU is also too slow and the only efficient miners are built using specialized hardware.

Comment: True, but this project has a different purpose.